# Is there any way to customize the properties in _ _ NEXT_DATA__?

Tags: next.js

For example, modify the page attribute in **NEXT_DATA** before rendering to the HTML source。
Does Next.js 12 provide this modification capability?

try to update **NEXT_DATA**.page, but it doesn't work。

Because the website built with Next.js is being used for ASV scanning, the scan result fails due to the page attribute.